# FHIR Resource & Request URL for fetching the Specialities List

Tags: hl7-fhir

I would like to know what FHIR resource has to be used for bringing the list of specialities that are available for an organisation. These specialities must be used as an input for searching the encounters.

Use case:

I need to fetch the list of Specialities for an organisation. The list must be filtered using the speciality name rather than code.

Input parameters:
1. Organisation
2. Specialities

How to frame a request URL?

Can anyone please suggest the best way to achieve this use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're after is the HealthCareService resource - that tells you a specific capability available from a specific organization at a specific location.  If you want the names of things rather than just the codes, you may need to make a subsequent call to a terminology service to look up the display names for the codes.  While it's good practice for systems to always populate the "display" element in a Coding, not all systems will do so.